# NextJS access httponly cookie before each fetch request on external API

Tags: cookies, next.js, httponly

In my NextJS app I use external API for user authentication and processing other API calls. I use Flask app as an external API. When login is performed to the NextJS app I sent credentials to API and after user is authenticated, API responses with *Set-Cookie* header containing jwt access token. The cookie is set as **httponly** (I also tried not setting the cookie as httponly, but the result was same). The token is successfully set as it is visible in dev tools cookies section. I have the middleware function which controls every endpoint of the NextJS app if the user is authenticated. I am able to access cookies (*even the* **httponly**) inside the `middleare.ts` file, within the `NextRequest` object such as: `req.cookies.get('token')?.value`.

Example of middleware function in `middleware.ts` file, where cookies are accessible:

```js
export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const token = req.cookies.get('token')?.value // prints the token cookie value as expected
  //...rest of the code
}
```

However, I am trying to create built-in `fetch` wrappers, in my example case `POST` function defined inside `./fetch` folder. This `POST` function is called from inside specific functions representing different API calls e.g:

```js
import { POST } from "./fetch";

export async function somePingApiFetch(authData: User | PKI): Promise<SignInResult> {
  const result = await POST<SignInResult, User| PKI>('/ping', authData);
  return result;
}
```

The `POST` function is defined like so:

```js
import {getCookie} from "cookies-next"

export async function POST<T, U>(endpoint: string | URL, body: U, options?: any): Promise<T> {
    const token = getCookie('token')
    console.log(token) // undefined
    const url = new URL(endpoint, 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1')
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        mode: "cors",
        cache: "no-cache",
        credentials: "same-origin",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            // ...(token && {"Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`})
        },
        redirect: "follow",
        referrerPolicy: "no-referrer",
        ...options,
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
    });
    return response.json();
}
```

As you can see, in the commented out section, I am trying to access **httponly** cookie using `cookies-next` library, I also tried `js-cookie` and `cookies` library and none was able to access the cookie, no matter if the cookie is **httponly** or not... I need the cookie to use it to set `Authorization Bearer` header.

I am calling the `somePingApiFetch` and similary defined functions from components marked as `use client` as well as server components. In none I am able to access the token data from cookies inside `somePingApiFetch` function.

Can someone please try to help and explain what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I think you have to make sure that you have 'use server' in a file where you use your fetch request middleware function to tell Next.Js is a server side, so then you can access cookie using next js
`import { cookies } from 'next/headers'`

In my case I have following function where I'm able to read  httpOnly cookie and send it with Authorization headers.

```
 'use server'
    const cookieStore = cookies()
    const accessToken =cookieStore.get(localStorageKeys.accessToken)

    export const getPrices = async () => {
   const response = await 
   fetch(`${appConfig.BASE_URL}${apiEndPoints.prices}`, {
    cache: 'force-cache',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken?.value}`,
       },
     })
 //other stuff
  }
```